# Metric for partitions of a topological space

Tags: metric-spaces, set-partition, decision-trees

Let $X$ be a [topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space). Consider the set $B_X$ of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Definition) of $X$ such that every block of the partition is [simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space). How can one define a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) $d$ on $B_X$?

To help answer this, consider the following cases (of increasing complexity):

1. $X = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, and $B_X$ contains partitions of the form $1,\ldots,t_1|t_1 +1,\ldots,t_2| \ldots|t_{-1},\ldots,n$
2. $X = [0,1]$, and $B_X$ contains [partitions of the interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_an_interval) specified by $0=t_0 <t_1 < t_2<\ldots< t_{-1}=1$
3. $X = \mathbb{R}$, and $B_X$ contains partitions specified by $-\infty=t_0 <t_1 < t_2<\ldots< t_{-1}=\infty$
4. $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ and the $B_X$ contains partitions formed by hyperplanes perpendicular to the axes
5. $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ and the $B_X$ contains simply connected partitions

What would be an example of a non-trivial metric in these cases?

To give some context, this problem arose from trying to compare decision trees (as in machine learning) constructed from a common set of attributes: Each decision tree partitions the space of attributes with hyperplanes perpendicular to the axes.

I wonder if one can construct something similar to the [Wasserstein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) or the [earth mover's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance), i.e, the distance between two partitions is the minimum "cost" to convert one partition to the other. For case 1. above, if $P_1 = 1,2,3|4,5$ and $P_2 = 1,2|3,4,5$ are two partitions of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, then $d(P_1,P_2) = 1 $ because the $P_1$ to $P_2$ conversion involves moving just one element (3). But I'm not sure how to generalize this.

Comment: Are the partitions of $[0,1]$ supposed to be finite? Because there is nothing about the definition you’ve given of these partitions that implies there is a least $x_1.$

Comment: Also, are partitions into a single point allowed? Or is there some minimum condition, like the interior of each part must be non-empty?

Comment: You can assume the partitions are finite, and blocks with single points are allowed.